# Dynamic loading NET46 dll from NETCORE11

Tags: c#, .net, dll, asp.net-core, multiplatform

I have a `netcore1.1` library project using `EFCore` and more NETCore based libraries, which uses plugins.

some of the plug-ins was not ported into net-core and are targeting `net40` and `net46`...
and they are not targeting the frameworks of my running, loading, assembly.

Now it is logical, I will run into problems loading assemblies from different frameworks into my NetCore1.1 App...

Adding `net4x` to the frameworks list requires refactoring the code for both `.netCore` and `.net`, either way, one target won't be able to work with both framework's plug-ins.

How can I (from a NET-CORE App) run a plug-in in it's own environment that fits it? while maintaining the interface ?
Note: If it helps, My interface with the plugins is pretty plain, basic types.

**Edit:**
I try using `AssemblyLoader.Resolve`, and it when trying to reference
`{System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089}`,
(which surprisingly wasn't loaded from GAC), i loaded it from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6`,
gives me an exception:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL'.  
Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  
They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context.  
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you have `net46` in your framework list and `#ifdef NET46` the framework specific code?

Comment: @vcsjones that will require maintaining two sets of codes, 1 without `DepInj` using `EF6`, and another using `EF-Core`.  i rather have only `NET46` and leave NetCore aside.